# update Action bar menu inside a custom adapter class

Tags: android, android-activity

I developing a android app where i have to show a list of product. I am using a custom adapter for this . Each row of list showing a product image with add to cart button when user click the button i want to change the cart menu  that i show in my action bar .  to do that i need the view that showing the number but it is created on onOptionsMenuCreated() function of my activity.
so my question is how can i access  this textview in my adapter class to change it on on clicklistner in my custom adapter i pass context of my activity with product arraylist.

Comment: can you make your question more clear and use proper formatting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Main Activity class make your action bar menu related function public so that you can access from any other class like MainActivity.yourFunction();

Comment: thanks brother your solution work perfectly. Except One thing that i have use the same adapter in many other activity so the casting cause problem. But if i use a interface that have signature for that method and implement it in all my activity then i think It will work. Your comment?